# How can I create service of type BuildLifecycleAwareVirtualFileSystem using GradleUserHomeServices.createVirtualFileSystem()

Tags: flutter, gradle

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Gradle could not start your build.

> Could not create service of type BuildLifecycleAwareVirtualFileSystem using GradleUserHomeServices.createVirtualFileSystem().

> java.io.IOException: Access is denied

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              8.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with access. Check in `JAVA_OPTS`, specifically `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/srv/tmp/` to see if the service has write access to the folder.

You can set the write access to e.g.

```
sudo chmod 1777 /srv/tmp/
```